# Synology Plex docker YouTube-dl

Tags: docker, youtube-dl, multimedia, synology, plex

I have a Plex MM server running on a Synology DSM, and its working great for all me music, movies and tv shows.

Yesterday I use YouTube-dl from GitHub on my Mac and download a few videos from a YouTube chanel, then copy to my multimedia folder on Plex. After a few minutes the videos were available on my Plex library and I was happy.

Today I set a Task on my Synology to everyday at 5am run a user script like this:

```
echo "start downloading"
cd /
cd /volume1/myfoler
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list --playlist-start 1 --playlist-end 1 -format mp4
```

The Task run my own user, and videos get there with no problem, but they just don't apear on library.
Ig I check the file on Plex filesystem is there, but I the videos I think they are no readable on Plex. I can open in my PC or with Synology video player.

Since the MM folder have to be own by http user, so I change the script to make user http run the script:

```
sudo -H -u http youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLK--playlist-start 1 --playlist-end 1 -format mp4
```

don't load it also.

I even try manually user chown and chmod 777 on the files and folders, and also don't work.

What I'm missing?

regards, LL